# Filtering Firestore database

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, cloud

Inside the app I have 4 different Tabs and I want to show the filtered data from firestore.

I have the following Tabs:

- All
- Music
- Fitness
- Comedy

The initial tab displays All data without filtering, the second tab displays the data that have tag 'music' and so on.

I copied the code 4 times and change the .where but this solution seems for me not the best one.

Here is my code of one of the tabs:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: 150.0,
              child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: Firestore.instance
                    .collection('eventsdata')
                    .orderBy('dateform')
                    .where('dateform', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: _timeminus1)
                    .where('platform', isEqualTo: 'Comedy')
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError)
                    return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      return new Text(
                        'Loading...',
                        style:
                        TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0, color: Colors.black38),
                      );
                    default:
                      return Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 179.0),
                        child: new ListView(
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: What is your question exactly ?

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: Hello, thank you both for the comments. The code is working but the stream is loading every time the user switch tabs. I would rather load the stream one time and after filtering it. How this could be done? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then your initial tabs displays all data unfiltered then I would save the data from this query and use it for the other screens. If you already have all your data on the device it makes more sense to filter the data on the device than to make multiple queries to firebase as you get charged per read / write. So I would save my data as a `List<MyClass>` then map that to a widget to display the data.
[How to filter list in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57270015/how-to-filter-list-in-flutter)
[Iterating through a list to render widegets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441168/iterating-through-a-list-to-render-multiple-widgets-in-flutter/50451020)
 Here these aren't tutorials but they should point you in the right direction they where the best material I could find

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: myInfo.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => InfoCard(myInfo[index]),
      ),
```

myInfo is your list and InfoCard is a reusable widget if you don't know about making reusable widget I attached a link if you don't need all that it can be as simple as a text widget.

[Reusable Custom Widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441168/iterating-through-a-list-to-render-multiple-widgets-in-flutter/50451020)

[Flutter: The power of small and reusable widgets](http://Flutter:%20The%20power%20of%20small%20and%20reusable%20widgets)

Comment: Hi wxyankees424, thank you for the comment. It's exactly what I was looking for. Do you know some tutorial I could follow to save the data to a list? I had been checking in here but I'm getting really confused. Once again thank you and have a happy Easter.

Comment: updated content if this has answered your question you can accept this answer if not if will help you out further.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the feedback. I checked the links and other sources in internet but I still not able to execute it.  From your comment I understood:
1. Store the fire store stream in a list 
2. Use this list to filter the content.
I think I managed to achieve the first point but after I got lost in retriever the data. I should still use the stream builder to retriever the data or how should this be done? Once again thank you in advance for all help.

Comment: ok if you ill post some sample code in a little bit to help you

Comment: Ok so I am posting code that is helpful to you. I want to understand better what you have understood and what you are still struggling with. So you should have one ```StreamBuilder``` that then saves your data to a list most likely a list of a class you have defined so ```List<MyClass>``` you then filter out the elements of the list you want when you are ready to display them on the specific tabs using ```list.where```  save that to a list specific to that tab so you have a master list then a list on each tab hope this isn't to confusing

Comment: there are multiple ways to display information from list to widget but the easiest way i think is to map it.  I see you are using a ```ListView``` I will post code above on mapping lists to widgets

Comment: Hello, thank you for the feedback. I managed to put it to work using provider instead of a stream builder. Thanks for all the help. Have a Happy Easter.

Comment: Happy Easter,  just so you know when you ask a question you if someone gives an acceptable answer you should accept it and upvote it so it can help others in the future. hope you have a good day :)